# Find occurance of characters in array of object using js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have array of object with few words I want to know occurance of each word  and push into key value pair format

```
let words = ["aabbbc", "dddeeef", "gghhhii"]

Output
[{a:2, b:3,c:1}, {d:3,e:3,f:1}, {g:2,h:3:i:2}]
```

Comment: Include what you have tried.

Comment: @ShriHariL actually i am unable to get how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***This is a classic [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task*** where one maps the array of strings and for each string creates the character-specific counter-statistics while reducing the string's character-sequence (`...split('').reduce( ... )`) and by programmatically building an object which counts/totals each character's occurrence.

```js
console.log(
  ["aabbbc", "dddeeef", "gghhhii"]
    .map(string =>
      string
        .split('')
        .reduce((result, char) => {
          result[char] = (result[char] ?? 0) + 1;
          return result;
        }, {})
    )
)
// [{a:2, b:3,c:1}, {d:3,e:3,f:1}, {g:2,h:3:i:2}]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let words = ["aabbbc", "dddeeef", "gghhhii"]

const occurences = (w) => {
    const obj = {};
  for (const c of w) {
    if (obj[c] === undefined) obj[c] = 0;
    obj[c]++;
  }
  return obj;
}

const arr = words.map(w => occurences(w));
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let words = ["aabbbc", "ddeeef", "ghhhii"]
    let newArr = []
    
    words.forEach((e,index)=>{
        e.split('').forEach(n=>{
            if(!newArr[index]){
                newArr[index]={}
            }
            if(!newArr[index][n]){
                newArr[index][n]=0
            }
            (newArr[index][n]>=0) && ++newArr[index][n]
        })
    })

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to keep it easy and readable:

```
const words = ['aabbbc', 'dddeeef', 'gghhhii']
const output = []

for (const word of words) {
  const result = {}
  for (const letter of word) {
    result[letter] = result[letter] || 0
    result[letter]++
  }
  output.push(result)
}

console.log({ output })
```